# Cannot Install React-Birthday Sample Webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, react, react-webpart

I'm trying to install React-Birthday webpart from [Github repository sample webparts](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-birthdays) but facing issue when running `npm i`.

Things I've tried:

- I tried to remove node_modules, clear cache, install npm multiple times
- I copied the source to another solution and build it from scratch -> didnt work cause most probably the SPFX version was higher than the one supported by the solution
- I made share I go through read me file and target the exact versions supported by the sample solution to build the proper environment
- I've gone through spfx matrix to make sure of the versions compatibility: (spfx 1.16.1, node 16.13.0, npm v8, ts 4.5)
- I've also installed python27 as the logs shown and added environment variable to the exe location

but all done with no luck. What am I doing wrong?

This is the error log after running npm i:`ERR! code 1 npm ERR! path C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-sass npm ERR! command failed npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library= npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok npm ERR! gyp verb cli [ npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\code\\react-birthdays\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=', npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' npm ERR! gyp verb cli ] npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0 npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.13.0 | win32 | x64 npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild [] npm ERR! gyp verb command clean [] npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory npm ERR! gyp verb command configure [] npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH npm ERR! gyp verb` which`failed Error: not found: python2 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at F (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at E (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed  python2 Error: not found: python2 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at F (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at E (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) { npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed   code: 'ENOENT' npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed } npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed Error: not found: python npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at F (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at E (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed  python Error: not found: python npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at F (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at E (C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29) npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-gyp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5 npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:198:21) { npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed   code: 'ENOENT' npm ERR! gyp verb`which`failed } npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe npm ERR! gyp verb check python version`C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import sys; print "2.7.0
npm ERR! gyp verb check python version .%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];"`returned: %j npm ERR! gyp verb get node dir no --target version specified, falling back to host node version: 16.13.0 npm ERR! gyp verb command install [ '16.13.0' ] npm ERR! gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Cannot find module './buffer-entry.js' npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Require stack: library=" npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\code\react-birthdays\node_modules\node-sass npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.13.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0 npm ERR! gyp ERR! This is a bug in`node-gyp`. npm ERR! gyp ERR! Try to update node-gyp and file an Issue if it does not help: npm ERR! gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues> npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 7`